# $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{r-1} dx<\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

We know that  the Gamma function  is

$$\Gamma(r)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{r-1} dx \  \ (r>0).$$

My Question is: What can we say about the integral

$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x} x^{r-1} dx \  \ (r>0)?$$

Is it convergent or so?

Comment: The problem posed in the body is at great remove from what you ask in the title.  In particular you seem to intend to pose the definite integral over the whole real line $\mathbb R$ rather than just the nonnegative real numbers.  For an arbitrary exponent $x^{r-1}$ will not be well-defined where $x\lt 0$, unlike the case $x\ge 0$.  So you should reconsider the problem formulation or clarify what you've written so far.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the integrand has exponential growth at $-\infty$. (There is also an ambiguity about what $x^{r-1}$ even means when $x<0$ and $r$ is just positive.)